# apt-get upgrade gives GPG Error

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

How would I go about fixing this error? I have pycharm installed through a ppa that I have been using for years in various computers.

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY DD969F10A7E2BCD2
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mystic-mirage/pycharm/ubuntu xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
DD969F10A7E2BCD2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: You need to add it to apt:

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DD969F10A7E2BCD2

First and incorrect answer:

They changed the GPG key they use to sign packages. Try running this in a terminal:

gpg --recv-keys DD969F10A7E2BCD2

Comment: gpg: no keyserver known (use option --keyserver)
gpg: keyserver receive failed: bad URI

Comment: Try:  gpg --recv-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu DD969F10A7E2BCD2

Comment: worked but still same error on apt-get update

Comment: It needs to be added to apt, try running ```sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys DD969F10A7E2BCD2```

Comment: keyserver.ubuntu.com
--recv-keys
DD969F10A7E2BCD2
gpg: requesting key A7E2BCD2 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key A7E2BCD2: public key "Launchpad PPA for Mystic-Mirage" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)